# How to apply transaction isolation level for MVC app with lazy-loading is on?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions, structuremap, transactionscope

We have web MVC app where EF's DbContext (POCO) derived class is managed by StructureMap and set up as http-scoped life-cycle. How can we set up specific isolation level for our repository (for instance Read Uncommitted) with lazy-loading is on? Isolation level is usually set up by TransactionScope which is disposable and not supposed to live for the entire Http request like DbContext is. Our controllers know nothing about all this Database specific stuff and work with repositories only, however ViewModel can automatically initiate Db queries by accessing lazy-loaded properties. 
Thank for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [custom action filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs) which will use transaction scope with read uncommitted and use that action filter for actions where you want this behavior. Transaction is not bound to repository. Transaction is started either by controller or used service layer because business logic defines boundary of the transaction.

Comment: I think this make sense in case you need specific isolation level being provided for ViewModel data lazy loadings. Just one more remark: TransactionScope should be instantiated in OnActionExecuting and disposed in OnResultExecuted to make it work for ViewModel during View rendering. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @YMC: If you are making use of lazy loading in your views then you are probably doing it wrong. ViewModels should have the all the data when you supply them to the view. Triggering a lazy load operation from inside the view is never a good idea ...